# Why does shorting two cells in series heat them up?

Tags: electricity, everyday-life, home-experiment

I tried this with two 9V batteries that you can interlock easily and they heat up a lot. Why does this happen? The internal resistance of the batteries would be quite small so why would they still heat up a lot due to Joule heating?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: War story. A crescent wrench has low resistance. It was dropped between the contacts of a switch in an electrical distribution yard. Blue ball killed the guy.

Comment: What's a blue ball?

Comment: The wrench turned into plasma.

Comment: They heat up less if the resistance is high and the other way around. Lithium batteries have low internal resistance and if shorted they become so hot that they often explode. Watch out before shorting stuff!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short circuit current for a fresh 9V battery is around 4A.  With the series connection, the emfs add so the power dissipated by the total internal resistance is roughly:

$P \approx 18V \cdot 4A = 72W$

In other words, you'd expect the combination to produce, for a relatively short time, about as much heat as a 75W light bulb.

Comment: Could there also be some additional heat due to the exothermic reaction of the battery occurring so fast?

Comment: How did you get that 4A? Thank you

Comment: Oh well OK you assumed the internal resistance is 1 ohm I suppose

Comment: @Dakatine, I didn't assume an internal resistance, I just *looked up* the typical short circuit current for a fresh 9V battery.